# Codeigniter when i submit more than one option of form_multiselect(), Only just the last one that saved on database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Codeigniter when i submit more than one option of form_multiselect(), Only just the last one that saved on database.

in my view :

```
<label>Trimestres :</label>
    <div class="controls" >

      <?php $options = array(
            'trim1'  => ' Premier trimestre (Janv,Fév,Mars)',
            'trim2'    => ' Deuxiéme trimestre (Avril,Mai,Juin)',
            'trim3'   => ' Troisiéme trimestre (Juill,Aout,Sept)',
            'trim4' => ' Quatriéme trimestre (Oct,Nov,Déc)',
             );
     echo form_multiselect('trimestres', $options , $this->input->post('trimestres') ? $this->input->post('trimestres') : $participant_sport->trimestres, 'id="trim"'); ?>

     </div>
</div>
```

in my controller :

```
public function inscriresport ($id = NULL)
{

// Fetch a participant or set a new one
if ($id) {
$this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get($id);
count($this->data['participant_sport']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'participant non trouvé';
}
else {
$this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get_new();
    }


    // Process the form

$this->participantsport_m->array_from_post(array('matricule', 'nom', 'prenom', 'beneficiaire', 'sexe', 'telephone', 'date_naissance', 'date_inscription_sport', 'trimestres' ,'sport_montant_paye', 'sport_debut_periode', 'sport_fin_periode'));
$this->participantsport_m->save($data, $id);
redirect('admin/agent/profile/3608');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/agent/inscriresport';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

The function array_from_post() is defined on application\core\MY_Model.php :

```
public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

in my model :

```
public function get_new()
```

{

```
$participant_sport = new stdClass();

$participant_sport->matricule = '';
$participant_sport->nom = '';
$participant_sport->prenom = '';
$participant_sport->beneficiaire = '';
$participant_sport->sexe = '';
$participant_sport->telephone = '';
$participant_sport->date_naissance = '';
$participant_sport->date_inscription_sport = '';
$participant_sport->trimestres = '';
$participant_sport->sport_montant_paye = '';
$participant_sport->sport_debut_periode = '';
$participant_sport->sport_fin_periode = '';
  return $participant_sport;
```

}

Any help Please? i think that must be an array but i don't know how to do it?

i thing that i must do something like that :

```
foreach($_POST["strategylist[]"] as $s) {
    # do the insert here, but use $s instead of $_POST["strategylist[]"]
    $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO sslink (study_id, strategyname) " .
       "VALUES ('$id','" . join(",",$s) . "')")
        or die("Insert Error: ".mysql_error());
}
```

to insert more than one option selected in one row but i don't know how to do it in codeigniter

the get() function :

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE){

    if ($id != NULL) {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE) {
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else {
        $method = 'result';
    }

    if (!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    }
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If select name (in HTML tag) is `trimestres` it will always remember last selection. Use `trimestres[]` as a name to get array with all selected values`

`<select name="trimestres[]" multiple …`

**By the way:**
I don't know how `array_from_post()` works but it has to change `trimestres[]` values to one string to save all of them in one column. It is hard to search/add/delete one value if all values are in one string. It is "[SQL Antipattern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)". You could do another table in database for `trimestres` - one value in one row.

**Edit:**

It will change all arrays into string with elements connected by `,`. Not tested.

```
public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {

        // print_r($this->input->post($field));

        if( is_array( $this->input->post($field) ) ) {
            $data[$field] = join(",", $this->input->post($field));
        } else {
            $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
        }

        // print_r($data[$field]);

    }
    return $data;
}
```

**Edit:**

Not tested.

```
public function inscriresport ($id = NULL)
{

    // Fetch a participant or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['participant_sport']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'participant non trouvé';

        // explode to array
        // print_r($this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres); // test before explode

        // $this->data['participant_sport']['trimestres'] = explode(",", $this->data['participant_sport']['trimestres']);
        $this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres = explode(",", $this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres);

        // print_r($this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres); // test after explode

    } else {
        $this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get_new();
    }


    // rest of code 

}
```

Comment: Add `print_r($_POST['trimestres']);` before `array_from_post()` to see if you get all values. If `array_from_post()` is your own function add code to question.

Comment: Done, sorry i just added the code of array_from_post() to question and some specifications in the end of question

Comment: You are right - you will have to use `join(",", trimestres[])`

Comment: and i thing i have to use a foreach loop but i don't know where and hwo ? i'm new on php codeigniter.

Comment: See my answer. All is in `array_from_post`.

Comment: Okey thanks i will test it and tell you if its ok or no. one moment please

Comment: You can add `print_r($data[$field]);` inside `array_from_post` for test.

Comment: it works fine, thank you, but when i want edit the values in the database i can't retrieve them. when i want creat a new one i use this admin/agent/inscriresport/ with agent is the controler and when i want edit i use this admin/agent/inscriresport/27 (27 is the id of rows that have for exemple 4selected values, this 4 items don't show when i want edit). i think i must change something in my get() function. it added on the question. thanks for your preciouse time.

Comment: `trimestres` (in database) is as string. You have to [explode](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it to array to use it in multiselect. And do this in controller - don't touch `get()`. `get()` is part of oryginal framework.

Comment: how can i do it? i realy don't know

Comment: See `explode to array` in answer.

Comment: I edited the controller just like your code, but when i load this page admin/agent/inscriresport/27 nothing load it's blank. I think the array data in controler must be an one-dimensional array or no?

Comment: Because in view i have this : $this->input->post('trimestres') ? $this->input->post('trimestres') : $participant_sport->trimestres, i retrieve data from participant_sport

Comment: Controler is for that kind of code `$participant_sport->trimestres = ( $this->input->post('trimestres') ? $this->input->post('trimestres') : $participant_sport->trimestres );`. Controler get data from Model and `post()` (and etc.), make some decision, modify data and send them to View. In View use only `$participant_sport->trimestres` - at most `isset($participant_sport->trimestres) ? $participant_sport->trimestres : "some static, default value";`

Comment: I change this ($this->input->post('trimestres') ? $this->input->post('trimestres') : $participant_sport->trimestres) by only this ($participant_sport->trimestres) but nothing hapen, i got the nlank page

Comment: If you get blank page it can be some PHP error but server doesn't show PHP errors message.

Comment: how can i show them in codeigniter? more than one time i got this blank page in other case but i don't know where is the probleme. there is some suggestion than can help me to show errors?

Comment: Now i get errors,i'm just adding this ini_set('display_errors', 1); to index.php has 0 inside 1, it shown this errors : function: {main}( ) file: ..\index.php:0 and  function : require_once(C:\wamp\www\system\core\CodeIgniter.php)  in file: ..\index.php:213 and function : call_user_func_array () in file: ..\CodeIgniter.php:359' and function : Agent->inscriresport() in file: ..\CodeIgniter.php:0 any help?

Comment: by the way: You can use `print_r` to test variables value; you can add `echo "before function_name/loop/etc.";` and `echo "after function_name/loop/etc.";` to see what script is doing step by step and catch which line of code doesn't work. You can write to CodeIgniter log instead using `echo` (see: [errors](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html)). And you can use CodeIgniter [Profiler](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html) to get other info.

Comment: Error message show line number in `index.php` and `CodeIgniter.php` but expect some line number in function `inscriresport` in your controler. Try to use `echo` and `print_r` (as in my answer) to find place of problem.

Comment: Try to use `$this->data['participant_sport']->trimestres` in place `$this->data['participant_sport']['trimestres']` in controler - I changed last code in my answer (again).

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to solve this problem that I found today.
you have to serialize the $_POST['trimestres'] array just after array_form_post .
the this array will save to database as a serialize string.

```
public function inscriresport ($id = NULL)
{

// Fetch a participant or set a new one
if ($id) {
$this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get($id);
count($this->data['participant_sport']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'participant non trouvé';
}
else {
$this->data['participant_sport'] = $this->participantsport_m->get_new();
    }


    // Process the form    
$this->participantsport_m->array_from_post(array('matricule', 'nom', 'prenom', 'beneficiaire', 'sexe', 'telephone', 'date_naissance', 'date_inscription_sport', 'trimestres' ,'sport_montant_paye', 'sport_debut_periode', 'sport_fin_periode')); 
$data['trimestres'] = serialize($_POST['trimestres']);

$this->participantsport_m->save($data, $id);
redirect('admin/agent/profile/3608');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/agent/inscriresport';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

When you just need this data back form database just use php unserialize() function . 
Hope it will help to do this easily ....

-thanks